# Objective C: Any issues in having 2 NSNotifications set up in a single class?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsnotifications

I have a class with 2 NSNotifications implemented

```
    //Set up notifications
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(getData)
                                                 name:@"Answer Submitted"
                                               object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(reloadTable)
                                                 name:@"Comment Submitted"
                                               object:nil];
```

I would just like to check if it is ok to set 2 observers in a single class? Also when I remove observer, I am only removing one observer in dealloc method. Is that an issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is perfectly fine to have more than one observer in a single class. You should always unregister the observer once you're done with it.

More details on the Observer pattern in Objective-C can be found [here](http://www.numbergrinder.com/2008/12/patterns-in-objective-c-observer-pattern/).